# ie6 taking an extra margin of 50px; what is wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i am coding an exclusive ie6 css. my problem is it is taking an extra 50px for header div. i have fixed the size of the header to 109px whereas it is producing 159px, when i place any element below the header div it consumes the extra 50px. i tried display:inline as ie6 hacks, and it just reset the left margin. quite not useful for me.

here is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/aVc4S/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because of: 
`#left-logo img {
    width:295px;
    height:50px;`

Comment: lol. thank you.. yes it is. you answered just in time when i figured it out .. :)